# How to write blood pressure google fit

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I want to read and write blood pressure data to google fit. i tried but HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE is not available in my project.
i wnat to know how it write or how to compile HealthDataTypes.java to my project

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/write-bp-data) about *Write Blood Pressure Data*.

Your app can record blood pressure data by writing to the [`com.google.blood_pressure`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/HealthDataTypes.html#TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE) data type. In this data type, each data point represents a single instantaneous blood pressure reading. The data point contains fields for the systolic and diastolic pressure, body position during the reading, and location on the body where the measurement was performed.

To write a blood pressure data point, create a new [`DataSource`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource) of [`TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/HealthDataTypes.html#TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE), as shown in the following example.

```
DataSource bloodPressureSource = new DataSource.Builder()
        .setDataType(TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE)
        ...
        .build();

    DataPoint bloodPressure = DataPoint.create(bloodPressureSource);
    bloodPressure.setTimestamp(now.getMillis(), MILLISECONDS);
    bloodPressure.getValue(FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_SYSTOLIC).setFloat(120.0f);
    bloodPressure.getValue(FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_DIASTOLIC).setFloat(80.0f);
    bloodPressure.getValue(FIELD_BODY_POSITION).setInt(BODY_POSITION_SITTING);
    bloodPressure.getValue(FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_MEASUREMENT_LOCATION)
        .setInt(BLOOD_PRESSURE_MEASUREMENT_LOCATION_LEFT_UPPER_ARM);
```

Comment: Thanks. but how to get FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_SYSTOLIC.
this is not granded to my project.is it some way to sync them?